# Invalid field count for AggregateResult:

Tags: apex, soql, query, decimal, aggregateresult

Aggregate count error - please assist and excuse this basic mistake.
I am trying to count a number from the query and then to use it in some arithmetic.
Tring to get RemainingMonthsDec throws the error:

> System.SObjectException: Invalid field count for AggregateResult:
>   Trigger

Here is code - thanks

```
AggregateResult[] ActualizedAmount = [
    SELECT SUM(Amount__c )sum
    FROM Deal_revenue__c
    WHERE date__c >: StartDate
    AND Deal__c =: deal.id
    AND Amount__c != NULL
];
Decimal ActualizedDecimal = (Decimal) ActualizedAmount[0].get('sum');

AggregateResult[] RemainingRevMonths = [
    SELECT COUNT(id)
    FROM Deal_revenue__c
    WHERE date__c >: Thisday
    AND Deal__c =: deal.id
    AND Amount__c != NULL
];
Decimal RemainingMonthsDec = (Decimal) RemainingRevMonths[0].get('count');

Decimal RemainingAmount = deal.Campaign_Amount__c - ActualizedDecimal; 

Decimal ReaminingSplitAmount =  (RemainingAmount / RemainingMonthsDec);
```

Thanks for the solutions. Per my experience, a small change of making the alias something other than the exact same word used in the aggregate function  makes tracking and understanding the meaning of the alias easier. Example:

```
AggregateResult[] RemainingRevMonths = [SELECT COUNT(id) countalias 
                                        FROM Deal_revenue__c 
                                        WHERE date__c >: Thisday 
                                        AND Deal__c =: deal.id 
                                        AND Amount__c != NULL];

Decimal RemainingMonthsDec = (Decimal) RemainingRevMonths[0].get('countalias');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't alias the field. Either add a field alias (`count`), or get the first expression (`expr0`).

```
List<AggregateResult> aggregates = [SELECT count(Id) count FROM ...];

// OR

Decimal count = (Decimal)myAggregate.get('expr0');
```

---

Take a look at the **`Force.com SOQL and SOSL Reference`** for a more in depth explanation:

> ## [Using Aliases with `GROUP BY`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_alias.htm)
>
> You can use an alias for any field or aggregated field in a SELECT statement in a SOQL query. Use a field alias to identify the field when you’re processing the query results in your code.
>
> Specify the alias directly after the associated field. For example, the following query contains two aliases: `n` for the Name field, and `max` for the MAX(Amount) aggregated field.
>
> ```
> SELECT Name n, MAX(Amount) max
> FROM Opportunity
> GROUP BY Name
> ```
>
> Any aggregated field in a SELECT list that does not have an alias automatically gets an implied alias with a format `expri`, where i denotes the order of the aggregated fields with no explicit aliases. The value of i starts at 0 and increments for every aggregated field with no explicit alias.
>
> In the following example, MAX(Amount) has an implied alias of `expr0`, and MIN(Amount) has an implied alias of `expr1`.
>
> SELECT Name, MAX(Amount), MIN(Amount)
>       FROM Opportunity
>       GROUP BY Name
>
> In the next query, MIN(Amount) has an explicit alias of min. MAX(Amount) has an implied alias of `expr0`, and SUM(Amount) has an implied alias of `expr1`.
>
> ```
> SELECT Name, MAX(Amount), MIN(Amount) min, SUM(Amount)
> FROM Opportunity
> GROUP BY Name
> ```

Comment: Thank you. The practice using the same word as an alias in the documentation I find rather confusing.  I lost the alias when editing from a sum function and didn't understand the syntax well enough to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code syntax would be like:-

```
AggregateResult[] RemainingRevMonths = [SELECT COUNT(id) count 
                                        FROM Deal_revenue__c 
                                        WHERE date__c >: Thisday 
                                        AND Deal__c =: deal.id 
                                        AND Amount__c != NULL];

Decimal RemainingMonthsDec = (Decimal) RemainingRevMonths[0].get('count');
```

You should define the alias `count` so you can reference in code to access the data. It can be any other name.

Comment: N.B. `count` is an alias, not a variable